# Is there a API for developres for register cast apps?

Tags: google-api, google-cast, google-developers-console, google-cast-sdk, google-developer-tools

Hello there i'm in a situation where i need to register a lot of new cast apps and i'm wondering if there is any API to do this task instead of doing it manually one by one on the SDK Developer Console as the docs suggest. I already created one Cast app that is working correctly so i'm familiarized with this console. But i haven't been able to find any documentation regarding some API to make this proccess more automated.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have bulk registrations.